# Is an SSH key pair sufficient protection when port forwarding?

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I may be using the wrong language in my title. Here's my task: I currently go into an office where I use the local network to ssh into various Raspberry Pis running Rasbian. I plan to do this "port forwarding" thing that I recently stumbled upon, to have that same level of access from home.

Although the scenario is specific, I think the question is general: **If I set up port forwarding, and the ssh configs on each of these devices are such that a key pair is required (no password), have I checked all the basic security boxes? Or is there something else I should be doing to protect my devices?**

Comment: you are the network admin of this office? as you will need to have admin access on your office Internet entry point. if you open the port forward it will be a security issue depending of the vulnerabilities of the ssh connection. eg a DoS attack on the port you open. and your key pair user should not be root (you did not mention, so I just want to be sure).

Comment: it's a cobbled together startup. everyone is everything - which makes me the network admin :P key pair user is not root. Thanks for the tip about DoS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security checklists can be as long as you want and highly dependent on your organizations requirements. This is really a judgement call based on the risks, the effort required to implement them and the lost productivity associated with the security measures. You can go for the bare minimum (like your setup) all the way up to top secret-classified fortified bunkers with air gapped networks, armed security and fiber connections to reduce cross-talk between network cables. It's all a matter of cost and in some situations, either scenario can be justified. An internet QA website can't make this decision for you.

I can give some general guidelines:

- I don't think most companies would be happy with end-user or development machines directly connected to the internet (and I consider simple port-forwarding as directly connected to the internet, as there is no real filtering done between the attacker and the machine). A "jump host" or a VPN setup would mitigate this problem.
- SSH keys can be considered secure in theory, however these things can be highly implementation specific. OpenSSH has a good reputation when it comes to security. Personally I wouldn't worry about using keys too much.
- You didn't mention anything about updates. If you connect a machine to the internet, updates become one of the most important factors as it's the only way to protect yourself against new vulnerabilities.
- In addition to updates, logging also becomes much more important. You probably want to have some idea of what happened *when* one of your machines is compromised (note that there is no **if**, it's **when**) as your business can probably not afford to wipe *everything* when there is a breach.
- Your current setup has no MFA, which is very trending in the security world now, and something you might want to consider.

As this is mostly a judgement call, I would ask someone in your company whose responsibility fits this kind of decision and defer to them. Inform them of the facts, the risks and the gains and let them make a decision.

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question well. Actually my situation only warrants 2 hours of work to get this set up - so it seems like the answer is don't do it. In any case, would you happen to know if plug and play services exist to help me here? All I need is to log in and fix something that's broken if I'm working from home that day.

Comment: In a professional context I would highly recommend you hire a professional to deal with this. "A dude on the internet" is not a good source for security related information. There are several third-party solutions, but product recommendations are out of scope on SuperUser as they are highly specific, mostly opinion based and get outdated fairly quickly. If my answer was adequate, please mark the answer as such so it's easy to find for other people with a similar question.

Comment: in case MFA is a concern (regarding the current news/security threads about it), be aware that it is only an issue if another part of the system was breached. and @mtak - I like your answer and would add that the logging should also be secure and maybe offloaded from the server itself..